# Using Android ARCore Required in an existing app

Tags: android, arcore

I have an existing android app in the store, available for API 16+. 
I created a small module inside my app, using ARCore. If I update the app, and I use ARCore Required ( https://developers.google.com/ar/distribute/ ), will my old APK still be available for devices that do not support ARCore?

Let's say my current version code is 100. If I create an APK with ARCore Required, and version code 200, this new apk will be available for all devices that support ARCore, but apk version 100 will be served to all other devices, right?

That's my understanding, I just wanted to confirm. Thanks.

I guess the pain, for me, will be the fact that I will need to always create two builds, for example 101 and 201, and upload them both, when adding features that are common. However, I would prefer this, instead of serving the larger (maybe much larger) ARCore APK to all of my users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm you can use the above mentioned technique to apply a Google Play filter and target only devices capable of AR.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an update, you can always attach an existing APK. By this you can say that you want to keep old release and for supported devices add new release.

It is always safer to test it in the beta channel first.